# Variable line limits with ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am plotting a number of time series on a single pair of axes. The series cover a range of timeframes - e.g. some cover a year, some only a few months. I would like the resulting charts to plot one line per series, with each line visible only for the timeframe that the series covers.

The data behind the chart is a format of a dataframe (`meltdf2`) with 4 columns - Month, user, score and risk.

A simplified version would be:

```
Month   user   score   risk
jan-18  A      1       high
feb-18  A      1       high
mar-18  A      2       mid
apr-18  A      1       high
feb-18  B      1       high
mar-18  B      2       mid
apr-18  B      3       low
mar-18  C      3       low
apr-18  C      3       low
```

Currently, the chart displays three lines, one for each user, each line covering the full with of the chart.
Ideally, I would have a chart with line `A` would span the full width of the chart, while lines `B` and `C` would only span part of the chart.

I have tried including NA values for the months not covered by `B` and `C` but their lines still span the full chart. Failing the NA value route, I have tried to manually set multiple colours on a single line but this doesn't seem to work.

The current code I am using is as follows:

```
#create colour palette based on discrete risk levels - used to specify manual colour scale in plot.
pal <- c("High"="red2","Mid"="gold","Low" = "limegreen","NA"= "NA")

#create plot with line and points.
#colour of points based on colour column of meltdf2
ggplot(data = meltdf2, aes(x = Month, y = user, group = user)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = meltdf2$risk, size = 3)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = pal, limits = names(pal)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month" , date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "darkgrey"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

This code produces the following chart:

[image: Risk Level chart]

Ideally, the section of each of the dashed grey lines prior to the first datapoint for each series would not be displayed.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the snippet of data you have provided. Also, your snippet of data doesn't seem to be the data.frame you're supplying to ggplot, based on the column names / ggplot arguments, so that is confusing as well. My best guess would be `ggplot(df, aes(Month, score, group = user)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(colour = colour)) +
  scale_colour_identity()`

Comment: @teunbrand I've made some edits to the question - hopefully this is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by modifying the dataframe (`meltdf2`) behind the chart. Using `na.omit(meltdf2)` removed rows where no data existed for each series and prevented the line from plotting.
End result below:
[image]